# Fluentd td-agent don't recognize custom plugin. Unknown input plugin

Tags: plugins, fluentd

I created a custom plugin called in_vCenterCrawler.rb and added it to the folder /etc/td-agent/plugin. In the file /etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf I have:

```
<source>
  @type vCenterCrawler #Also tried with in_vCenterCrawler
  port ****
  host '**.*.***.***'
  vCenterPort ***
  user "****"
  password "****"
</source>
```

When I run the command 'td-agent' I get the error:

```
config error file="/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf" error="Unknown input plugin 'vCenterCrawler'. Run 'gem search -rd fluent-plugin' to find plugins
```

If I run 'gem search -rd fluent-plugin' I get:

```
The program 'gem' can be found in the following packages:
* ruby
* rubygems
```

But after finding the information in https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/plugin-management I assumed I needed to transform my plugin into a gem, so I executed the command "td-agent-gem install vCenterCrawler" and I got:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'vCenterCrawler' (>= 0) in any repository
```

At this point I'm confused and I don't know if this is a bug or if I'm missing something. I'm using td-agent 0.12.40.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I found what is the problem.

In the configuration file the type name should be the one defined in the plugin and not the plugin file itself.

In my plugin I have:

```
module Fluent
  class VCenterCrawlerInput < Input
  # First, register the plugin with the name vCenterCrawler
  Fluent::Plugin.register_input('vcentercrawler', self)
...
```

Which means I registered the plugin name as being vcentercrawler. I used the:

```
@type vcentercrawler
```

and it worked!